# I get a ParserError when I try to import Openzeppelin contracts in vscode

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

Here are my import statements

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

And this is the error I keep getting:

```
ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File not supplied initially.\nimport "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this particular error by updating solc.